# Handling directory paths that conflict with library paths using requirejs

Tags: requirejs

I'm curious if there is a way to safely use paths that include paths already defined in the requirejs config. **I realize that the "simple" solution would be to make sure paths don't conflict. This is more a question to preserve lexical directory naming clarity.**

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        backbone: 'path/to/backbone',
        underscore: 'path/to/underscore'
    }
});
```

So I named my paths in the config and to keep things clean I want to store all of my backbone specific files in a sub-directory also called `backbone` so things are logically separated using a description directory.

```
define(['backbone/models/my-model']);
```

If I use the following define when declaring a new model it won't work because it'll try and read it as `path/to/backone.js/models/my-model`. *Is there a way to get it to use the backbone directory instead of the path to the library?*

I've tried namespacing the paths in the config to something like `lib.backbone` and `lib.underscore`, but I think requirejs requires these not be changed due to the internal working of the the library.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to fix this is to add a mapping to your `paths` setting that is more precise than the one that is messing up your path resolution. So:

```
paths: {
    backbone: 'path/to/backbone',
    underscore: 'path/to/underscore',
    'backbone/models': 'backbone/models'
}
```

Unfortunately, if you have other subdirectories you need to cover under `backbone/`, you'll have to add one new path per subdirectory.